# What's the grammatical term for a sentence that begins with a descriptive noun phrase, followed by a complete sentence?

Tags: grammar, sentence

For example:

- *A powerful sword forged by a famous blacksmith, it has seen endless battles.*
- *A cheap yet versatile mini-tank, the Ice Golem provides a wide range of uses ...*
- *The sister of the Witch, she has moderate hitpoints ...*
- *The capital ship of the Terran fleet, this powerful spacecraft is capable of firing a Yamato cannon ...*

That is, a sentence (perhaps following a title) that begins with a descriptive noun phrase, followed by a complete sentence. I remember reading sentences with a similar structure in item descriptions in many video games, but I can't remember a grammatical term to describe such sentences when I want to discuss them with others.

Comment: Thank you. I googled 'left dislocation', and most of the examples are colloquial, and it is seen as a discourse function, such as topicalization. But my examples are not colloquial. I believe I have seen such usage in many genres of written texts, not only video games. So is it also discourse-driven in written language? Or is it a formal structure widely accepted in formal English for some time? By the way, English is not my mother tongue, so such nuances are elusive to me.

Comment: The examples are all appositives -- note that they are each followed by a synonymous NP that they are intended to describe or name. A very standard structure, as the existence of a punctuation mark (colon) for it, and its standard deployment in definitions.

Comment: I disagree, Appositives are always post-head modifiers or supplements. How can "it" possibly be an appositive modifier of "A powerful sword forged by a famous blacksmith"?  And how can "she" be an appositive modifier of "the sister of the witch"? In any case, appositives are always specifying, not ascriptive.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/601225/2085).

Comment: You might be interested in the concept of topic-prominent languages: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topic-prominent_language

Answer (score 2):

I'd say that the initial NPs are predicative adjuncts. Here are some clearer examples:

> *A proud teetotaller, John stuck to water while the others drank*
> *champagne.*
>
> *A teacher by profession, Ed was soon recruited to lead the students.*

The initial NPs, a proud teetotaller" and "a teacher by profession" are predicative because they relate to a predicand, i.e. "John" and "Ed" (cf. *John was a teetotaller.* / *Ed was a teacher.*).  They are also adjuncts in clause stucture;  hence the term 'predicative adjunct'.

Note that predicative adjuncts are not restricted to NPs; we can also have PPs and AdjPs;

> *In a bad temper, as usual, John walked on ahead of the main party.*
>
> *Unwilling to accept these terms, Max resigned.*

Lexico [link](https://www.lexico.com/definition/predicative_adjunct) describes a predicative adjunct as "a word or phrase that amplifies or completes the predicate of the sentence", though I would add that it must be a supplement (e.g. an appendage), and it must relate to a predicand (usually the subject of the sentence).

Answer (score 0):

These are often considered appositives. Although appositives usually follow their referents, it is possible for them to precede them, especially at the beginning of a sentence. [Purdue OWL](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/grammar/appositives.html) gives several examples, including:

> **A bold innovator**, Wassily Kandinsky is known for his colorful abstract paintings.

[ThoughtCo](https://www.thoughtco.com/how-to-build-sentences-with-appositives-1689672) gives another example:

> **A dark wedge**, the eagle hurtled earthward at nearly 200 miles per hour.

Comment: I disagree, Appositives are always post-head modifiers or supplements. No exception.

Comment: @BillJ Yeah, we've had this conversation before. Noted.